# RHEL 6.5 iso issue

Tags: mysql, redhat, installation, rhel6, iso

the company Im currently working was able to installed redhat 6.5 in their VM and they uploaded the Rhel 6.5 iso in the redhat server. I was able to install the apache and the php but when I tried to install the mysql, it gives me the dependency problem. Also, the VM is not connected to the internet as of the moment that is why Im using the iso to install mysql. Please click the link below: 
[image: Dependency problem for the mysql]

I mounted the iso and was able to install the other things but not the mysql. I've downloaded also those broken dependency file from the internet and try to install them but it seems that there are some .rpm file requires to connect to the internet. 
Do you have any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: This is not a place to seek urgent help. If you need urgent help, hire someone.

Comment: Hi, my bad. it is not so urgent but i need to know the solution of this problem.

Comment: First, connect to the Internet. Then license the system. Then _update_ the system. Then try again.

Comment: Unfortunately, my boss dont want to connect the vm to the internet as of the moment. I dont know the reason why. That is why I just download the rhel 6.5 iso and mounted it. can install other rpm files except those files that have some dependency problem. is there other solution for this without involve an internet connection? any help or idea will be much appriated

Comment: Replace your defective boss and then see my previous advice :)

Comment: Actually, prior to this vm, we were able to install redhat 6.5 to another server and we were able to install everything but for this new server, it will not allow us. Dont know the reason why. Is possible that before I will install the mysql, I need to install first perl then mysql? The other vm, we didnt install perl, just mysql right away.

Comment: And this is what sucks about Red Hat. Licensing... Outdated ISOs. You probably have RHEL support. You can call them for guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. While I was checking what were the software installed in the Redhat 6.5, I noticed that the mysqls that were installed were 32bit and the Redhat is a 64bit. So I remove first the mysql-libs which was installed first and then removed other that were dependency of mysql-libs. After removing them all, I just re-install them again using the ISO that was mounted in the system. The iso mounted in the system is a 64bit. It is now able to install everything.